# How to calculate the effective interest rate of a loan that must be paid back with interest as lump sum

Tags: loans, calculation, interest-rate

An example question asks:

> Student Bank has agreed to lend you funds to complete the last year of
>   your degree. The bank will lend you $2,400 today, if you agree to
>   repay a lump sum of $4,000 in 4 years from now. What is the
>   approximate annual rate of interest that Student Bank is charging you?

The solution given in the textbook [here](https://www.coursehero.com/file/p557lc3/4-What-would-be-the-value-of-Karens-15000-in-three-years-if-it-earned-an-ann/) says that the answer is 14%. However, I've calculated that $1600 in interest over four years amounts to $400 per year, which is 17% of $2400. I believe the correct answer should be 17%.

Am I wrong? and why?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you were actually paying $400/year in interest, then your 17% would be a closer approximation of the correct answer of 16 <sup>2</sup>/<sub>3</sub> % in such a case.

However, that case is not matching the question. Interest is *not* being paid each year. Rather, the interest is accumulating into the debt until you owe $4000 total at the end of the four years.

Consequently, you need to determine the effective annual interest rate; i.e. the rate that when **compounded** four times and applied to the starting amount of $2400 yields the ending amount of $4000. Hint: Your calculations will need to include calculating the fourth root of some number.

Comment: Thank you for your explanation. If the question was modified to be over a 20 year time span, I would need to find a 20th root? Is there a better way?

Comment: @Imray Yes, in that case you would need to find the 20th root, or equivalent, raise the number to the 1/20th power. Here's a video at Khan Academy that [explains the relationship between radicals and unit-fraction exponents](https://www.khanacademy.org/math/algebra/rational-exponents-and-radicals/introduction-to-rational-exponents-and-radicals/v/radical-expressions-with-higher-roots).

Comment: Aside from using root/power, you can get closer to the right answer through approximation. e.g. by guessing the interest rate and appyling it 4 times (or 20 times, in the modified case). e.g. try 1.12: `2400*1.12*1.12*1.12*1.12=3776.45` ... so 1.12 is too low, try higher; 1.14: `2400*1.14*1.14*1.14*1.14=4053.50` ... too high; a bit lower, etc.

Comment: I suggest you search Khan Academy for additional videos about interest rates and compounding.

Comment: Do you know if there's a quick way to solve this on a financial calculator?

Comment: Indeed there is. See the example titled *"Compute the interest compounded annually"* further down the page at http://www.utdallas.edu/~merville/calculator.htm ... make sure to change the calculator's number of compounding periods per year as instructed earlier in the page.

Comment: Raising an arbitrary number to an arbitrary power is a function on calculators used by middle-school kids.  It's not like you are required to perform a manual calculation.